# Keep side bar full height

Tags: css, flexbox

I am pretty bad with css, so I was wondering how I can keep my sidebar full height, even though it doesnt have full content.
This is my css:

```
#wrapper {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
background-color: yellow;
}

#wrapper .sideBar { 
background-color: green;
width: 200px;
margin-left: 10px;
overflow-x: hidden;
padding-top: 20px;
}

#wrapper .productsBox{
width: 250px;
margin: 3px;
}
```

But I get this result[image]

However I want a result that looks like this:
[image]

Any idea how I can fix this? And I want to have a responsive view, so when a user use phone to browse it displays a decent view. Thats the reason I use the wrapper.
html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <form method="get" id="sortForm">
        @Html.DropDownList("sort", new SelectList(ViewBag.sortOptions,"Value","Text"), new {@class="form-control", onchange = "sortingChanged()" })
    <div class="sideBar">
            <strong>Search for products</strong>
            <input type="text" class="searchBar" name="SearchString" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" placeholder="Search.."/>            
        <hr />
        <h6>Price</h6>
            <div>
                <input type="number" class="priceRangeInput" name="minPrice" value="@ViewData["MinPriceFilter"]" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');"  />
                <span>Min</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="number" class="priceRangeInput" name="maxPrice" value="@ViewData["MaxPriceFilter"]" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" />
                <span>Max</span>
            </div>
            <br />
            <hr>
        <h6>Types</h6>
        

            <button type="submit" class="btn customGreen" >Set filters</button>

        </form>
        
        <br />
    </div>
    

        @{

            foreach(var p in @Model)
            {
                <div class="productsBox">
                <div class="card">
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@p.Id">
                    <img alt="@p.Name" class="contain" src="@p.FilePath" height="300" style="width: 100%;" />
                </a>
                <h3>@p.Name</h3>
                <p class="price">@p.Price kr/@p.Unit</p>
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@p.Id">
                    <button class="customGreen">See more</button>
                </a>
            </div>
            </div>
            }
            
        }
        
</div>
```

Comment: I can only think of a method that uses grid, but that might not be an option...

Comment: add your html code please. We need to see what you did and how your items are in relation to each other so we can give you answers that work with your approach

Comment: Oh, my bad. I added the html now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
html, body {
  height: 100%
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%; /* to set height to 100% */
}

body {
  margin: 0; /* to remove default margins */
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%; /* to set height to 100% */
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.sideBar {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 200px;
  color: #fff;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.product-wrapper {
  width: calc(100% - 200px); /* 100% - (sidebar width) */
}

.productsBox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 3px;
  background: #2f910f;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="sideBar">
      Sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="product-wrapper">
      <div class="productsBox">
        Item
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add side bar and another containts in different divs and add this code to it:

```css
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
.sidebar{
  background-color:red;
  width:50%;
}
.containts{
  width:50%;
  background-color:green;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="containts">
    containts
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you want your wrapper to have full height of your screen: then add #wrapper{height:100vh}

Comment: The wrapper height is not the problem, its the sidebar height. I tried what you suggested, but I the items are placed below sidebar.

Comment: did you add width for the .sidebar and .containts? and add flex-wrap:no-wrap to your wrapper.

Comment: as you can see in my code, the sidebar and and the containts must be in different divs

Answer (score 0):

You should take `.sideBar` out of the `#wrapper` container and apply `width: calc(100% - 210px)` to `#wrapper` (i.e. the width of the container/window minus sidebar minus its left margin). That way both together will be 100% wide, but the contents of `#wrapper` will not go under the sidebar.

Comment: By doing that all the items just went below the sidebar.

Comment: Did you apply `margin: 0` to `body` to reset the default margin of the browser? that might be the cause for the behaviour you describe. Also adding `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` might be advisable in case you use borders to include them in the `width` measurements.

Comment: I added margin: 0 to the body, the result is the same.

Comment: The essential detail is to apply a `width` to the `#wrapper` that makes it fit into one line with `.sidebar`. I don't know the rest of your code, but there might be other margins, paddings, borders, spaces etc. that might add a few pixels, so you have to find that out for yourself. One way to proceed would be to increase the  pixel value to be subtracted from the 100% width, like `width: calc(100% - 250px)`, and if that works, slowly decrease that value again until you find one that works.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code in css it worked for me

**height: 100%;**